# Parametric equation for plane

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

> [image]
>
> Determine a parametric equation for A.

The problem gives me the following hint, but I don't see it:

The parametric equation can be written as:

$$\vec{OP}=b+xu+yv, x\in [a,b], y\in [c,d]$$

Comment: Your equation doesn't make much sense.... and what it $P$

Comment: @Bye_World I know what the answer is, but I don't understand it.

Comment: The trick here is that $P$ represents any point in $A$. You are trying to write an equation in two parameters that "hits" every point in $A$. Notice that you already have a vector $\mathbf{b}$ that points to $B$. But then you are given vectors $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{u}$, and furthermore $\mathbf{b}+\mathbf{v}$ is the vector that points to the tip of the $\mathbf{v}$ vector shown there in the diagram. Does that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector $\vec b$ points to $B$.  The vector $\vec b + \vec v$ points to point one unit up on that grid.  So what about the vector $\vec b + t\vec v$ for some $t\in[0,1]$?  It would be somewhere *in between* $\vec b$ and $\vec b + \vec v$.  So the set of all points $\vec{OP}(t) =\vec b + t\vec v$ for $t\in[0,1]$ would be the line segment along the grid from point $B$ to the point one unit up.

Like $\vec{OP}(s) = \vec b + s\vec u$ for $s\in[0,1]$ would be the line segment starting from $B$ and going one unit *right*.

So what if you wanted to end up somewhere *within* the parallelogram with sides $\vec{OP}(t) =\vec b + t\vec v$ for $t\in[0,1]$ and $\vec{OP}(s) = \vec b + s\vec u$ for $s\in[0,1]$.  Well you'd want to go *some* distance in the $\vec v$ direction **and** some distance in the $\vec u$ direction.  It would be $vec{OP}(s,t) = \vec b + s\vec u + t\vec v$ for $s,t\in[0,1]$.  For any choice of $(s,t)\in [0,1]^2$, you'll end up a little bit over to the right and a little bit up -- but *within* (including on the boundary) the parallelogram you see on the grid with point $B$ at its lower left corner.

But that's not the parallelogram we want to parametrize.  We want to parametrize $A$.  So first we need to shift over.  Instead of starting $s$ and $t$ at zero, we could start them at negative numbers and then we'd be left and below the point $B$.  Notice that the lower left corner of $A$ is $\vec b -2\vec u -\vec v$.  So we'll want to start our intervals at $-2$ and $-1$ respectively.  Then the upper right corner is $\vec b -\vec u + \vec v$.  So we'll want to end our intervals at $-1$ and $+1$ respectively.

Well then we can immediately write down the answer:

$$\vec{OP}(s,t)=\vec b+s\vec u+t\vec v,\quad s\in [-2,-1], t\in [-1,1]$$

Make sure you understand why this works.